# backtick " ` " in request body in bash shell script while calling CURL

Tags: bash, azure-databricks

I'm writing CURL COMMAND

HTTP_Method : POST

API : api/databricks/query

```
Request body  {"query":" GRANT SELECT,READ_METADATA,USAGE on DATABASE `DB` to `userID` " }
```

The query,I have execute using POSTMAN it's working

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<databick_workspace-url>/api/sql/databricks/query' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"query":"GRANT SELECT,READ_METADATA,USAGE on DATABASE `DB-NAME` to `userID` " }
# Working, And user can access DB
```

I believe the problem is with backticks,

```
// Function 
function grantReadAccess() {
  local path="/api/sql/databricks/query"
  local url="https://<databricks-workspace-url>/${path}"
  printf 'curl %q' "${url}"
  local DATABASENAME="DB-NAME"
  local userID="userID"

  local content="GRANT SELECT,READ_METADATA,USAGE on DATABASE \`${DATABASENAME}\` to \`${userID}\` "
  echo "------------$content" 
  // OUTPUT Here : GRANT SELECT,READ_METADATA,USAGE on DATABASE `DB-NAME` to `userID`
  // Same I have to pass in request body
  local permissionToGroup=$(
    curl -X POST "${url}" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${authtoken}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "query": \"'"${content}"'\" } ')
    //Required in this {"query":"GRANT SELECT,READ_METADATA,USAGE on DATABASE `DB` to `userID` " }

  echo "${permissionToGroup}"
}

// Tried In Postman insted of using backtick
 1. Single Quote "'" {"query":"GRANT SELECT,READ_METADATA,USAGE on DATABASE 'DB' to 'userID' "
 2. Blacket "(" {"query":"GRANT SELECT,READ_METADATA,USAGE on DATABASE (DB) to (userID) "

Error

{
  "query": "grant SELECT, READ_METADATA, USAGE on DATABASE 'DB' to 'useID' ",
    "data": null,
    "error": " org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: \nOperation not allowed: grant(line 1, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\ngrant SELECT, READ_METADATA, USAGE on DATABASE 'DB"
}
```

The above function is not working,

Comment: Could you please do mention what is the error you are getting? Also what parameters/data points are acceptable by your API is also important to know here, you mention dummy samples but sensible ones so that we could try to help cheers

Comment: Use `jq` to compose your JSON data

Comment: BTW, bash doesn't treat backticks as special when they're just being expanded as data. (If it did, it would be impossible to write secure code handling untrusted data). They only get special handling when they're processed _as syntax_, and that only happens when they're present in your code, not your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use a tool that understands JSON when you need to build JSON. In this context, the widely-accepted tool is for the job is `jq`.

```
curl -X POST "${url}" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${authtoken}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d "$(jq -n --arg content "$content" '{"query": $content}')"
```

Comment: Thank you Working

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, but I'll guess you're having problems in this part:

```
-d '{ "query": \"'"${content}"'\" } '
```

That will get you literal backslashes before the double quotes around your content, since backslashes inside single quotes are inserted literally. You could swap that for `-d '{ "query": "'"${content}"'" }'` or `-d "{ \"query\": \"${content}\" }"`

Comment: Even that isn't guaranteed to escape `content` as valid JSON -- try having a `content` that contains newlines, double quotes, etc.

Comment: Thank you Working now

Comment: Good to know it helped! Please accept the answer if it was a good answer to the question.